# Invisible Model properties?

Tags: java, playframework

I have a `Product` model that has some basic attributes,

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
public class Product extends Model {

    public String name;

    public String description;

    public static Finder<Long,Item> find = new Finder<Long,Item>(
        Long.class, Item.class
    );

}
```

a controller function that uses `find` to attain and pass a `List<Product>` to the desired view,

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

import models.Product;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result allProducts() {
        return ok(product_page.render(Product.find.all()));
    }

}
```

and the stated view that iterates over the list and displays these properties.

```
@(products: List[Product])

<h1>Here are the products:</h1>

<ul>
@for(product <- products) {
    <li>@product.getName()</li>
    <ul>
        <li>@product.getDescription()</li>
    </ul>
}
</ul>
```

Everything looks fine (at least to me)... but the compiler tells me this:

```
value getName is not a member of models.Product
```

What am I doing wrong? (the route is fine, application.conf is setup correctly, evolutions are correct as well...)

Answer (score 0):

`Product` does not have *getter* methods

Comment: Play automatically generates the getter and setter methods as long as I dont supply my own handwritten ones in the source... at least that is what's stated in the documentation: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaEbean EDIT: I manually added the getter method for the name, and I am still having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 <li>@product.description</li>
```

BTW: Your finder should use as a second type the class of the current model

```
public static Finder<Long,Product> find = new Finder<Long,Product>(
    Long.class, Product.class
);
```

Comment: I think I might be encountering a bug. I did your suggestions, but now the browser cant connect to the Play server at all... When I am back on my computer I can copypasta the stack trace for you.

Comment: Yes, use pastebin.com, show us the whole Product model, your whole view and errors that are displayed